# URL has expired Device Farm AWS

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, aws-device-farm

I was unable to find a solution to this error, I run selenium test with pytest to aws device farm and sometimes this error appears, making the test unstable.
Could someone please care to explain why this happens and sometimes it doesn't? I haven't been able to find anything about it.

```
def check_response(self, response):
    """
    Checks that a JSON response from the WebDriver does not have an error.

    :Args:
     - response - The JSON response from the WebDriver server as a dictionary
       object.

    :Raises: If the response contains an error message.
    """
    status = response.get('status', None)
    if status is None or status == ErrorCode.SUCCESS:
        return
    value = None
    message = response.get("message", "")
    screen = response.get("screen", "")
    stacktrace = None
    if isinstance(status, int):
        value_json = response.get('value', None)
        if value_json and isinstance(value_json, basestring):
            import json
            try:
                value = json.loads(value_json)
                if len(value.keys()) == 1:
                    value = value['value']
                status = value.get('error', None)
                if status is None:
                    status = value["status"]
                    message = value["value"]
                    if not isinstance(message, basestring):
                        value = message
                        message = message.get('message')
                else:
                    message = value.get('message', None)
            except ValueError:
                pass

    exception_class = ErrorInResponseException
    if status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_ELEMENT:
        exception_class = NoSuchElementException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_FRAME:
        exception_class = NoSuchFrameException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_WINDOW:
        exception_class = NoSuchWindowException
    elif status in ErrorCode.STALE_ELEMENT_REFERENCE:
        exception_class = StaleElementReferenceException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_VISIBLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotVisibleException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ELEMENT_STATE:
        exception_class = InvalidElementStateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR \
            or status in ErrorCode.INVALID_XPATH_SELECTOR_RETURN_TYPER:
        exception_class = InvalidSelectorException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_IS_NOT_SELECTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotSelectableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_NOT_INTERACTABLE:
        exception_class = ElementNotInteractableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COOKIE_DOMAIN:
        exception_class = InvalidCookieDomainException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_SET_COOKIE:
        exception_class = UnableToSetCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SCRIPT_TIMEOUT:
        exception_class = TimeoutException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = UnexpectedAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_ALERT_OPEN:
        exception_class = NoAlertPresentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_NOT_AVAILABLE:
        exception_class = ImeNotAvailableException
    elif status in ErrorCode.IME_ENGINE_ACTIVATION_FAILED:
        exception_class = ImeActivationFailedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.MOVE_TARGET_OUT_OF_BOUNDS:
        exception_class = MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException
    elif status in ErrorCode.JAVASCRIPT_ERROR:
        exception_class = JavascriptException
    elif status in ErrorCode.SESSION_NOT_CREATED:
        exception_class = SessionNotCreatedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_ARGUMENT:
        exception_class = InvalidArgumentException
    elif status in ErrorCode.NO_SUCH_COOKIE:
        exception_class = NoSuchCookieException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNABLE_TO_CAPTURE_SCREEN:
        exception_class = ScreenshotException
    elif status in ErrorCode.ELEMENT_CLICK_INTERCEPTED:
        exception_class = ElementClickInterceptedException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INSECURE_CERTIFICATE:
        exception_class = InsecureCertificateException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_COORDINATES:
        exception_class = InvalidCoordinatesException
    elif status in ErrorCode.INVALID_SESSION_ID:
        exception_class = InvalidSessionIdException
    elif status in ErrorCode.UNKNOWN_METHOD:
        exception_class = UnknownMethodException
    else:
        exception_class = WebDriverException
    if value == '' or value is None:
        value = response['value']
    if isinstance(value, basestring):
        if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
            raise exception_class(response, value)
        raise exception_class(value)
    if message == "" and 'message' in value:
        message = value['message']

    screen = None
    if 'screen' in value:
        screen = value['screen']

    stacktrace = None
    if 'stackTrace' in value and value['stackTrace']:
        stacktrace = []
        try:
            for frame in value['stackTrace']:
                line = self._value_or_default(frame, 'lineNumber', '')
                file = self._value_or_default(frame, 'fileName', '<anonymous>')
                if line:
                    file = "%s:%s" % (file, line)
                meth = self._value_or_default(frame, 'methodName', '<anonymous>')
                if 'className' in frame:
                    meth = "%s.%s" % (frame['className'], meth)
                msg = "    at %s (%s)"
                msg = msg % (meth, file)
                stacktrace.append(msg)
        except TypeError:
            pass
    if exception_class == ErrorInResponseException:
        raise exception_class(response, message)
    elif exception_class == UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
        alert_text = None
        if 'data' in value:
            alert_text = value['data'].get('text')
        elif 'alert' in value:
            alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
        raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
```

> ```
>   raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
> ```

E       selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: URL has expired

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a remote URL for accessing selenium sessions on AWS Device Farm, you specify when that URL expires. If you specify a value too low, the URL will expire during your test, resulting in a `URL has expired` message.

For more information, look at the [`CreateTestGridUrl`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/APIReference/API_CreateTestGridUrl.html) documentation and view the `expiresInSeconds` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much